# getSupportedPreviewSizes() is an ordered list?

Tags: android, android-camera

Acording to android docs [Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29) returns

> "a list of Size object. This method will always return a list with at
>   least one element."

Does anyone knows if that list is ALWAYS ordered by size?

As far as I can tell, in all devices I've tried the list is ordered... but don't know if this is always true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen this list non-ordered. I am speaking about a few dozen devices from different manufacturers and sw upgrades. But there is no guarantee. And the order may be ambiguous: what is "smaller": 640×480 or 720×400? And for some devices, even decent devices from first-tier manufacturers, there may be bugs in this list. E.g. **Galaxy Nexus** claims that it supports 320×240, and you can set this resolution, but the camera remains in 640×480.

Comment: Seems to be like you say, it's _'always'_ ordered, but there is no guarantee.

By the way, good point on the "smaller" thing.